# Many to Many in flask

Tags: flask, many-to-many

I'm currently working on a small web app for a friend. I've run into an issue with organizing my code and I'm hoping someone can offer some guidance.

Here's the problem: I have two models that have a many-to-many relationship, and I'm not sure where i must create a table that connects the two models. I currently have all of my models in one folder, but I'm not sure where to put the code for the table.

I'm using flask, and I'm looking for advice on the best way to organize my code and create this table.

I know the code must be something like this:

```
user_channel = db.Table('user_channel',
    db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
    db.Column('channel_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('channel.id'))
)
```

My Problem is where I put this, I want my code tidy.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!